# What is the purpose of the `Shepard` function in R package `MASS`?

Tags: r, multidimensional-scaling

The function `Shepard` is listed in the help file for `MASS::isoMDS`, but nothing is said about it.

What does this function do?

Comment: I suppose this could just as easily be a question on StackOverflow. Oh well.

Comment: Did you want it migrated? (I think there's a statistical question beneath this.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be a function to do the calculations to draw Shepard diagrams - which plot similarity (or sometimes dissimilarity) vs distance.

A Shepard diagram plots MDS distances on the y-axis vs the input 
proximities (/distances/similarities/dissimilarities) on the x-axis.

For an ordinal MDS there will be a monotonically descending (ascending) "line" (being the approximated distances) while for metric scaling you'll get an actual line.

There's a rough ASCII example [here](http://www.analytictech.com/borgatti/mds.htm)

The example in the help on the function you point to seems consistent with that.

[image]

(that's straight from the example at the end of the help, with the minor change of making the line red so it stands out better)

Also see

Jan de Leeuw (2005),
"Shepard Diagram,"
*Encyclopedia of Statistics in Behavioral Science*,
Volume 4, p. 1830,
Brian S. Everitt & David C. Howell, Eds
John Wiley & Sons, Ltd, Chichester

[Author's own link](http://gifi.stat.ucla.edu/janspubs/2005/chapters/deleeuw_C_05g.pdf)